# Hov to setup a "nohover"

Tags: css, image, hover, fancybox

I have a hover for a fancybox in the body that works fine, but on the same page in a masthead I have ajximagerotator which also works fine.  The issue is that I do not want the masthead to have the hover attribute.  So how can I setup a "nohover" for the masthead.  Being a novice, any help would be appreciated.

Hover code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"       
href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    a.fancybox img {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -o-transform: scale(1,1); -ms-transform: scale(1,1); -moz-transform: scale(1,1); -
 webkit-transform: scale(1,1); transform: scale(1,1); -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -
ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; -webkit-
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    } 
  a.fancybox:hover img {
    position: relative; z-index: 999; -o-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); -ms-transform
   scale(1.03,1.03); -moz-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); -webkit-transform: 
   scale(1.03,1.03); transform: scale(1.03,1.03);
   }
   </style>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML or setup in jsfiddle

Comment: this is in the head html. Also as a Novice I don't know what jfiddle is or does.  thanks

Comment: You are applying `:hover` effect to the selector `.fancybox`. Just don't set that class to elements you don't want them to have that `:hover` effect. See http://jsfiddle.net/zUq5Z/ (image on right doesn't have class `fancybox`).... or better, use another class for the effect and keep the `fancybox` class for fancybox http://jsfiddle.net/zUq5Z/1/